# Using Interop.Excel, Workbooks.open() returns null

Tags: .net, excel, office-interop

I have meet a weird problem.In my console app,there is only one file which Workbooks.Open() opens to return null nor a Comb_Object.And in my test app,it can correctly return.
When I change the file name from '人员信息模板.xlsx' to any other like 'aaa.xlsx',it can correctly open this file.
I searched in Google.Someone said it may be a permission problem,and I set Everyone totally control to this file.It doesn't work.

Interop.Excel version:14, 0, 4756, 1000

Excel file is created by Excel 2016

Following is my Code

```
Application app = null;
Workbook curWB = null;
Worksheet curSheet = null;
app = new Application();
app.Visible = false;
app.UserControl = true;
app.DisplayAlerts = false;
//filename is C:\Users\29561\Desktop\AccmulateInfoTool\AccmulateInfoTool\bin\Debug\2018春季信息\原始邮件下载\人员信息模板.xlsx
curWB = app.Application.Workbooks.Open(filename);
//curWB is null now
curSheet = curWB.Worksheets[1];
```

Comment: Looks to be thread culture issue where it is not able to read those characters.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me, just testing with the file name, not the folder names in Chinese (?). Note that I do set CultureInfo, which is often necessary with Excel. I don't know if that has anything to do with it...

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        Excel.Workbook wb = null;
        Excel.Worksheet ws = null;
        try
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlApp.Visible = true;
            xlApp.UserControl = true;
            wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Test\\人员信息模板.xlsx");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
        finally
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
            ws = null;
            wb = null;
            xlApp = null;
        }
    }
```